# Update animation before transition Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a site using Vue Js and I want to transition between router-views. There are many different possible for the transition depending from to which screen you go (for example a fade in or a slide in). I want to use a switch statement for all the possible combinations, it is working however it updates after the transition, so it's always one way behind. How can I update the transition before the route updates based on `from` and `to`? My current code in `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <div class="app--wrapper">
      <transition :name="transitionAnimation">
        <router-view name="login"></router-view>
      </transition>
      <transition :name="transitionAnimation">
        <router-view name="dashboard"></router-view>
      </transition>
      <transition :name="transitionAnimation">
        <router-view name="moviedetail"></router-view>
      </transition>
      <transition :name="transitionAnimation">
        <router-view name="watched"></router-view>
      </transition>
      <transition :name="transitionAnimation">
        <router-view name="savedlist"></router-view>
      </transition>
      <transition :name="transitionAnimation">
        <router-view name="profile"></router-view>
      </transition>
    </div>
    <Navigation></Navigation>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from './components/Navigation'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Navigation
  },
  data() {
    return {
      transitionAnimation: 'fade'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      if (to.name === 'dashboard') {
        switch(from.name) {
          case 'watched': this.transitionAnimation = 'slide'; break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Having all of those router-views defeats the purpose of a router view...

Comment: But, have a look at this page https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#per-route-transition

Comment: It looks like you have that dynamic transition thing right. Are you sure you're trying to transition from a route named `'watched'`? The way your code is it wouldn't have any effect otherwise. Try getting rid of the switch statement and have it set `this.transitionAnimation` to `'slide'` regardless of the origin route and see if that changes it.